# UIBarButtonItem selector gets called when viewDidLoad(), instead of touching only

Tags: xcode, swift, uikit

I have a UIButtonBar created programmatically in my code, and It works great. However when I navigate between the View Controllers, it calls  the selector immediately when viewDidLoad() and I want to gets called only when I touch it, of course.

My code:

```
var barButton:UIBarButtonItem!

viewDidLoad()
{
        barButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        barButton.title = "Show"
        barButton.action = "didPress"
        barButton.target = self
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton

       UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(barButton.action, to: barButton.target, from: self, forEvent:nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your last line is calling it. Just remove that line to not call it.